# Recursively crawl data folder and create multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, recursion, multidimensional-array

So I have the following situation. In my project folder I got a 'data' folder that contains .json files. These .json files also are structured in nested folders.

Something like:

```
/data
    /content
        /data1.json
        /data2.json
    /project
        /data3.json
```

I'd like to create a function that recursively crawls through the data folder and stores all .json files in one multidimensional array, which makes it relatively easy to add static data for use for my project. So the expected result should be:

```
$data = array(
    'content' => array(
         'data1' => <data-from-data1.json>,
         'data2' => <data-from-data2.json>
    ),
    'project' => array(
         'data3' => <data-from-data3.json>
    )
);
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried the following, but this only returns the first level:

```
$data = array();
$directoryArray = scandir('./data');

foreach($directoryArray as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = $value;
}
```

Is there a neat way to achieve this?

Comment: This is a long ways from rocket science. What have your tried, or are you asking for quotes?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have updated my question.

Comment: _“I have tried the following, but this only returns the first level”_ – and where is the recursion in that?

Comment: This question is so weird, especially when you put a +50 bounty rep on it. This is such an easy task, if you just use Google and think about it a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use RecursiveIteratorIterator. Skip some directories like `.` and `..` . After this script loop other subdirectories.

```php
//just to remove extension filename
function removeExtension($filename){
    return preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $filename);
}

$startpath= 'data';
$ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($startpath), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
$result = [];
foreach ($ritit as $splFileInfo) {
    if ($splFileInfo->getFilename() == '.') continue;
    if ($splFileInfo->getFilename() == '..') continue;

    if ($splFileInfo->isDir()){
        $path = [removeExtension($splFileInfo->getFilename()) => []];
    }else{
        $path = [removeExtension($splFileInfo->getFilename()) => json_decode(file_get_contents($splFileInfo->getPathname(), $splFileInfo->getFilename()))];
    }

    for ($depth = $ritit->getDepth() - 1; $depth >= 0; $depth--) {
        $path = [$ritit->getSubIterator($depth)->current()->getFilename() => $path];
    }
    $result = array_merge_recursive($result, $path);
}

print_r($result);
```

My json files contain:

- data1.json: {"foo": "foo"}
- data2.json: {"bar": "bar"}
- data3.json: {"foobar": "foobar"}

The result is:

```php
Array
(
    [content] => Array
        (
            [data1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [foo] => foo
                )

            [data2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [bar] => bar
                )

        )

    [project] => Array
        (
            [data3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [foobar] => foobar
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm gonna close this issue, since there are too many people misunderstanding what I intended to ask.

Comment: @KeesvanLierop There you got your copy & paste solution, but still you have no idea how to solve your next recursive problem, because recursion is handled "behind the curtain" by the `RecursiveIterator` class.

Answer (score 2):

You do not really have to use `RecursiveIteratorIterator`. As a programmer you should always know how to deal with recursive data structures, may it be an xml content, a folder tree or else. You may write a **recursive function** to handle such tasks.

Recursive functions are functions which call themselves to process through data with multiple `layers` or `dimensions`.
For example, `scanFolder` function below is designed to process contents of a directory, and it calls itself when it is encountered with a sub-directory.

```
function scanFolder($path)
{
    echo "scanning dir: '$path'";

    $contents = array_diff(scandir($path), ['.', '..']);
    $result = [];

    foreach ($contents as $item) {
        $fullPath = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item;

        echo "processing '$fullPath'";
        // process folder
        if (is_dir($fullPath)) {
            // process folder contents
            $result[$item] = scanFolder($fullPath);
        } else {
            // for this specific program, you should perform a check here to see if the file is a json

            // collect the result
            $result[$item] = json_decode(file_get_contents($fullPath));
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

*IMO*, this is a cleaner and more expressive way to accomplish this task and I wonder what others have to say about this statement.

Comment: I like this solution, since it shows and teaches how to correctly deal with recursions. Unfortunately OP was only looking for a lazy copy & paste solution and claimed it to be "rocket science" which he doesn't understand.

Comment: @MarioWerner I was not entirely happy posting some handwritten solution against battle-tested native function. But I have done so anyway since I agree with you on your comment's main idea on answer above. I too think if OP is here with this specific question, he needs to understand what recursion is and how to handle it, rather than saving the day.

Answer (score -2):

I think that you can use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, [there is](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) an documentation about this class.

Comment: This is really only a comment. Also link only answer are frowned upon here at SO

Comment: @RiggsFolly I doubt PHP.net will be taken down anytime soon. So linking to PHP.net isn't that bad I think.

Comment: Its not only the link I was commenting on. This is not an answer under even the loosest description of an answer. **its a comment** and you have enough reps to be allowed to comment

Comment: The whole question is already pretty weird. Especially when the OP puts a +50 bounty rep on it for such an easy task. Seems like he only wants to have a ready-made copy & paste solution. If you ask lazy questions you get lazy answers.

Comment: @MarioWerner Well we dont have to lower our answers to the level of the question. But its definitely a **Do it for me** question

Comment: I am not agree with you @RiggsFolly :) . OP tried something as you can see in his update. It is difficult to do it, if you don't know that `RecursiveIteratorIterator` and `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` classes exist.

Comment: @AlexandreT You will get used to people throwing some half hearted attempt into an answer to avoid being closed for not attempting anything themselves. I would hardly call that a serious attempt at anything

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm not looking for a 'do it for me' answer, as my use case is slightly more difficult than my original question. The point I was struggling with refers to fetching the data recursively and was asking for a basic example.

Comment: @RiggsFolly While I agree that the answer is low quality, it's not *"really only a comment"*. It contains the relevant class name to google (which is helpful information) and there is a link to the manual as well. Sure, some code or explanation would improve this immensly. But if you mod-flagged this answer as NAA, it would get declined, because even when you strip away the link, it *does* contain helpful info.